# Unable to locate transaction, unable to send any token

Tags: metamask

I have done atleast 5 transactions and all of them are just pending for over a day now. On metamask it says i should use more gwei but when i change it to even 30 gwei it still just is stuck forever.

Latest one is: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x950a62356c452cbaedff9ebf68306d0b1b8c20aabce96a345e85c2f46e0318ba

But the problem is, it's not even pending, you can't find it.

If i try to send a new transaction from this address its just going to get stuck with all the rest.

It's really a mess and all my tokens are just stuck, i can't even send them out somewhere else. They are basically rendered worthless unless i fix the problem somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transactions are not being broadcast to the Ethereum network (which is why you can't see them, even in pending, in etherscan.io).

This is not a result of your gas price, it is a bug with MetaMask possibly, or your internet connection etc..

The easiest solution (and this tends to work for most people) is to fully close Chrome and restart it - this usually "unblocks" MetaMask.

Comment: This is correct. 

I have restarted my router and reopened chrome and all the pending transactions went through after i sent new one.

Answer (score -1):

Is it an ERC20? If so, some logic not implemented in the contract can block your tokens and hold it forever.

https://medium.com/wepower/erc-standards-to-move-ethereum-forward-erc-20-erc-223-erc-721-e1712456449d

Comment: If this were the case the transaction would show up on etherscan.io in a failed state, which is not the case with the sample transaction OP posted.